# Column name aliases generated by Fluent NHibernate too long

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sybase

Given a table column name of `ColumnNameIsVeryVeryLong`.

FluentNhibernate generates SQL as such...

```
SELECT tablename0_.ColumnNameIsVeryVeryLong as ColumnNameIsVeryVeryLong2743_0_
FROM ...etc.
```

The problem is that the underlying Sybase database only supports identifiers up to 30 bytes, so the generated column alias `ColumnNameIsVeryVeryLong2743_0_`generates the following error.

```
Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseException : The identifier that starts with 'ColumnNameIsVeryVeryLong2743_0_' is too long. Maximum length is 30.
```

Is there any way to control the length of the column aliases that are generated?  Changing the column name is not an option.

Comment: BTW, Fluentnhibernate does not generate the SQL. Regular old NHibernate does that chore.

Comment: Which dialect are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Subclass the Dialect and override the max length:

```
public class DialectOverride: *BaseDialect*
{
  public override int MaxAliasLength { get { return 30; } } 
}
```

then specify the dialect when configuring:

```
new DatabaseConfiguration().Dialect<DialictOverride>()
```

Comment: Note that the SybaseASE15Dialect already sets MaxAliasLength=30, while the SybaseSQLAnywhere10Dialect (and 11 and 12) sets it to 127. And SybaseASA9Dialect inherits MaxAliasLength=10 from the Dialect base class.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a bug in NHibernate, where it fails to *correctly* account for MaxAliasLength:
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3899 (fixed in NHibernate 4.1)

The workaround is to subclass the dialect you are using to override the MaxAliasLength property and let it return something in the 10-20 range, which will leave plenty of room for the unique numerical suffix.